# KPI indicator for QlikView report update status. (Weekly and monthly updated)

Tags: qlikview

I have two reports, one that is updated monthly from the source, and one that is updated once per week.

I have a KPI report that I want to show red/green indicators if the report is updated this month/this week.

The last updated date is stored in a table and is loaded into QlikView. QVD_Id is the id of the QV report.

The monthly report is beeing updated around the 10th each month. I have created this set analysis that seems to be "almost" working.

```
=if(Max({<Day=, Date=, QVD_Id={1}, MonthCounter={"<=$(#max(MonthCounter))"}>} num(Date(Updated))-1,00) >= num(Dato),0,1)
```

What I ultematly want for this indicator, is for it to be red if has not been updated within a month, or actually if its not updated within the 6th working day of the month it should be red(But this requered som additions to the dimensions that I can do later).

I tried to do the same for the weekly report, but its not working:

```
=if(Max({<Day=, Date=, QVD_Id={2}, WeekCounter={"<=$(#max(WeekCounter))"}>} num(Date(Updated))) >= num(Dato),0,1)
```

What I want with the weekly updated report, is that it should be red if it's not updated by the 2nd day of the week(Tuesday).

Example of the facttable used:

```
QVD_Id  TotalLoad   LoadYear    LoadMonth   LoadDay LoadHour    Updated                 Date_Lnr  Source
1       200000      2014        2           5       10          .02.2014 10:56:31       19759     Source1
```

WeekCounter is 58 this week, and MonthCounter is 2. (WeekCounter is just continiuing from last year but that does not matter here).

Hope any of you have some more experience then me with this and can find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is close to what you want:

> // check is date less than the 6 in the month and not larger than max date -1 month 
>   if(num(weekday(Max(Date))) <= 6 and
>   num(weekday(AddMonth(Max(Date),-1))) <= num(weekday(Max({$}Updated))), 1,0)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me think in new ways, but the hard part is excluding / including selected values like day, month and year.